# How to add a form in CMS->Static blocks and send the mail in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

I had created a new menu using catalog->Manage Categories->Add subcategory->quick service.
In CMS->Static Blocks I have created the form but it is not working properly.The PHP code is not working.Please can anyone help me in creating the form in static blocks and send the mail.

My form

```
   <form action="" id="quickservice" method="post">
   <li class="fields">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="Servicetype" class="required"> <em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Service Type') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select name="servicetype" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" style="width: 150px;" />
                                    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
                                    <option value="Lab"><?php echo $this->__('Lab')?></option>
                                    <option value="Hospital"><?php echo $this->__('Hospital')?></option>
                                    <option value="Food"><?php echo $this->__('Food')?></option>
                                    <option value="Gym"><?php echo $this->__('Gym')?></option>
                                    <option value="Physio"><?php echo $this->__('Physio')?></option>
                                    <option value="Nurse"><?php echo $this->__('Nurse')?></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
            </div>
</li>
 </form>
```

Comment: create form as a .phtnl file then call static block ({{block type="core/template" template="page/page.phtml"}})

Comment: Assuming this form is in a template(You can't have PHP code in static blocks), you'll need to show the controller code where this form submits. You don't have action attribute in your form, in that case, it will submit to current URL. Mail will be sent via controller on which the form will be submitted.

Comment: "The PHP code is not working" Static Blocks will not parse php tag

Comment: Yes created the form.phtml and added the form.phtml in this path app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/quickservice/form.phtml.But what I need to write in static block content?

Comment: call this in your static block {{block type="core/template" template="quickservice/form.phtml"}}

Comment: @Minesh Patel Ok.But I need to create a form without using static block

Comment: Create Form as per @@Kothari and Controller Action as per @@Prateek

Comment: @MineshPatel Yes created as per @@Kothari and what I need to write in static block content?

Comment: you created form.phtml and call that php code under form.phtml then call {{block type="core/template" template="quickservice/form.phtml"}}

Comment: now call your phtml in static block for example

{{block type="core/template" template="quickservice/form.phtml"}}

Comment: @Mouni and remember to add action in your form to your controller action

Comment: @MineshPatel Ok.Can you please explain by selecting the Lab from dropdown list .The name field as to generate and by selecting the pharmacy field the upload image button has to be generate.How can I do this??

Comment: @Mouni well you can achieve that by js

Comment: @Minesh Patel How Can you Please suggest me.

Comment: @Mouni ahhh. create one js function and call that on change of select box.compare current value of select box and based on that create dynamic text/ file field and add that filed to your form.

Comment: @Minesh Patel Can you please provide any sample code to do this.I am new to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31694/discussion-between-minesh-patel-and-mouni).